# str_replace() works on WampServer but not on live server?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a function which builds a multi-line string that needs to be echo'd out as a JavaScript variable, so after the string is built I run it through `str_replace()` before returning it like this:

```
return str_replace("\r\n", "\\\r\n", $output);
```

Here's the weird thing: this works fine on my development machine running WampServer, but it doesn't add the slashes at the ends of the lines on my live server (VPS running Apache and the latest version of PHP).

Example:

```
return (str_replace("\r\n", "\\\r\n",
        'this
        is
        a
        test'));
```

Dev. machine:

```
this\ is\ a\ test
```

Live server:

```
this is a test
```

I've been looking through the documentation, but have no idea why this is happening. Any ideas?

**Solution:**

```
return (str_replace(PHP_EOL, '\\' . PHP_EOL,
        'this
        is
        a
        test'));
```

Comment: Is the production server running a linux variant? Your line endings might be getting converted by any FTP software you may be using.

Comment: @castis: You should post that as an answer.  I was about to.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with `PHP_EOL` it will make your life much easier when working across different OS environments.

Comment: If you consider that solution to be THE solution, you should mark Phillipe's answer below as the answer, and give him credit for it (since he all but quoted you the code you'd need).

Comment: @joequincy - I was planning on it, but you have to wait a certain amount of time before you can accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Huh. I've never encountered that limitation (only one question, and it wasn't answered that quickly) :P So consider me newly enlightened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In windows you have \r\n but in linux you only have \n, so the function doesn't match any \r\n

You should use `PHP_EOL` instead